# Can an electromagnetic field be created in a non-metallic coil?

Tags: electromagnetism

OK, so here's a simple one. When current flows through a wire, it produces a tiny magnetic field. If you bend the wire into a spiral, the fields of each loop merge together forming a field you can actually measure.

But does the conductor have to be *metal*, or would *any* conductive material work? E.g., would a plastic tube full of water still produce the same magnetic field? [Assuming the water has enough impurities to be considered a "conductor" to start with, which it usually does.]

**Edit for Clarification:** OP is talking about a simple electromagnetic coil, without regard to core material or application. Assuming Air Core, would a coil of water in pvc tubing, electrified, produce a measurable magnetic field?

Comment: Theoretically, yes, but the energy needed in such an poor conductor would make it impractical in size/performance.

Comment: Are you trying to make an electromagnet or a solenoid?

Comment: @horta What's the difference?

Comment: An electromagnet uses a core material that's usually ferromagnetic to increase the field strength of the coil. A solenoid is nothing more than a coil generating an electric field. Often solenoid's have an actuator in them that is magnetic and the actuator is then moved by the solenoid.

Comment: @Passerby I'm wondering why you've used "an" before "poor" instead of writing "a poor". Is it a typo?

Comment: @horta I'm aware that putting a suitable material inside a solenoid increases the magnetic field strength. I'm merely asking whether a non-metal solenoid, by itself, would produce any magnetic field to start with. (I don't have an application in mind, I'm just curious.)

Comment: That's what I figured you were asking. The other answer's didn't seem to comprehend that.

Comment: @Gurpreet I used impure before I changed it to poor and forgot to change the an to a. But even then, it's a common typo why even bother mentioning?

Comment: @horta I learned it the other way around. And M-W shows solenoid as defined as `a coil of wire usually in cylindrical form that when carrying a current acts like a magnet so that a movable core is drawn into the coil when a current flows`

Comment: @Passerby What's M-W? And I have no problem defining a solenoid as including the actuator, but the OP originally stated "does *conductor* have to be metal", and generally speaking the actuator does not have to conduct anything at all in any definition. So even with an actuator, the OP would be talking about the coil rather than the actuator.

Comment: Merriam Webster dictionary

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the flow of charge through anything constitutes current, and since current creates a magnetic field, the short answer to your question: "Can an electromagnetic field be created in a non-metallic coil?" is "Yes".

Answer (score 3):

**Yes**, you can make a solenoid without a metal wire. The best conductors aren't metal at all, they're ceramics (i.e. superconductors). Water with impurities will work fine as a solenoid.

If you decide to use an actuator, you'll obviously have to have that have some kind of ferromagnetism or conductivity in the actuator to be capable of induced currents, but this still doesn't require any sort of metal or magnetism on the solenoid coil.

Answer (score 2):

For the sake of ambiguity:

If by **solenoid** the intent is just a coil & such a coil is to carry current & thus generate a magnetic field.

Yes. Water can easily conduct electricity & with this electrical current flowing around the coil will produce an magnetic field.
How good compared to a coil made out of wire?  not that good Why? the radius of the coil. The radius influences the inductance and the length & turns influences magnetic strength

B=μI*n/l

L=μr²n²π/l

Could you make the insulation of a waterpipe the same as the enamel insulation on a metallic conductor?

If it is todo with a **solenoid** associated with linear movement:

Any conductor will do. The key here is the permeability of the material.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permeability_%28electromagnetism%29#Values_for_some_common_materials

Compare Iron ( 2.5×10−1 )  to water ( 1.256627×10−6 )  and more importantly to Air (1.25663753×10−6) as it would be an air-cored Solenoid

That is a factor of 20,000

Comment: So... it *would* still make a magnet, just a really feeble one?

Comment: It would facilitate making an electromagnet BUT it probably won't even be able to exert enough force to counteract its own weight in water. By probably I mean more than likely, I just would rather not go through the maths to prove it

Comment: So, basically we're talking a magnet *so* feeble you wouldn't even notice it? (Unless you use silly amounts of current.)

Comment: a silly amount of current which would cause the water to boil & would probably just about manage to move a grain of sand .

Comment: or just electrolyse it. ;-)

Comment: All solenoid's are air-core. You're comparing apples to oranges here. An electromagnet generally has a core, whereas a solenoid does not.

Comment: they have an air gap, not an aircore. especially if you take into consideration the OP question.

Comment: They have an air core, otherwise it's an actuator. The OP has up till now only specified they want to make a solenoid, not an electromagnet.

Comment: Please provide evidence of an aircored solenoid. OP title is referring to a solenoid (ie a coil that moves the plunger, as oppose to a coil around an iron core to move a plunger)

Comment: From wikipedia: "A solenoid is a coil wound into a tightly packed helix." You're assuming that the OP's not going to use the core space as an actuator. Instead, you're assuming that they want to build an electromagnet. When you compare a solenoid to an electromagnet, of course the electromagnet will win. They serve difference purposes.

Comment: exact same link: In engineering, the term may also refer to a variety of transducer devices that convert energy into linear motion. OP intention is unclear

Comment: I'm glad that you've made a provision in your answer, but you're still putting in a bias against a solenoid made of water. If you have a coil made of ionized water or a coil made of metal with the same properties, you'll have the **same** solenoid. Whether the OP can make that water solenoid practical is up to him. The OP just wants to understand concepts from the basic nature of the question, and you're throwing him/her curve balls.

Answer (score 0):

For a simple solenoid, yes, it has to me metal. Further, it has to be a ferrous metal.

A solenoid works by simple magnetism.  Energise a coil to attract a ferrous material.

There are other systems though, called *Linear Motors* which at first glance look like a solenoid, but in fact work on a completely different principle.  These use a powerful magnetic field to induce a current into a conductive non-ferrous material (commonly aluminium) which then in turn generates its own opposing magnetic field.  These two fields repel each other and the non-ferrous material moves.  It's how "Maglev" trains work.

Comment: But aren't solenoids usually made of copper - which isn't magnetic at all?

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding the OP's question. He's just talking about a coil. I don't see any indication that he's talking about an armature within a coil. The coil doesn't need to be magnetic or a metal at all.

Comment: @horta the problem is that solenoid has multiple similar meanings.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it would, but depending on the medium you'd run into some serious implementation obstacles. In case of water:

- Once a DC current flows through water, it begins to split into hydrogen and oxygen.
- You somehow have to prevent evaporation